# Is there any reason I should use VirtualPC over VirtualBox to run Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [virtual pc versus virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/22921/virtual-pc-versus-virtualbox)

I'm looking to have a virtual machine with Ubuntu installed on it.  I want to do some light development work on it.

I have access to a license for VirtualPC and I also could just use VirtualBox which is free.

Is there any reason that I should use VirtualPC over VirtualBox?

Comment: What kind of license do you have for VirtualPC? It's been totally free for years now.

Comment: @Shiki, so it is.  I noticed in my MSDN subscription that it was in the Licenses/Keys section.  Do you have an opinion on VirtualPC vs VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0):

No reason at all, VirtualBox is the way to go for VMs, if I would buy a License for software it would be VMWare.

Comment: But, if you already *had* a license to VirtualPC, are you saying that you would still use VirtualBox?

Comment: VirtualPC is very limited IMO, VirtualBox has a lot of support, and Oracle/Sun are doing a very good job on it, Ubuntu installed on it is perfect, the Seamless mode works great too.

Comment: I prefer VirtualBox, but it does also have its problems. For free software though, it's great.

Comment: Yep, USB Support isn't very good when using *nix as a host.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualPC is free too, at least it was the last time I tried it.  I've only messed with Ubuntu guests a bit, so not much help with that, but generally I like VirtualBox a lot more than the Windows VirtualPC.  For one thing, VirtualBox supports 64-bit guests and for another, scrolling works on my touchpad.  So, I'd start with VirtualBox.

(Note that Windows VirtualPC is the Windows 7 (host) version.  If your host is an earlier Windows version, you need to run Microsoft VirtualPC 2007.  At least, I think that's right, the names are confusing, and perhaps another reason to just go with VBox.)